# How can I split feign interface to smaller interfaces in spring5

Tags: java, spring, feign

How can I split big feign interface to many small interfaces in spring5?

It only works, when I explicitly set bean overriding in spring's configuration, but this is workaround, not the solution.

I have one big feign interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "eurekaService")
public interface FeignInterface { // many methods here }
```

I decided to split it into multiple smaller interfaces:

```
@FeignClient(name = "eurekaService")
public interface FeignInterfaceOne { // some methods here }

@FeignClient(name = "eurekaService")
public interface FeignInterfaceTwo { // some methods here }
```

Unfortunately, Spring 5 says I'm trying to register bean with same name for the second time and it throws exception during startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:472)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSetup(BaseSpecRunner.java:375)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSetup(BaseSpecRunner.java:370)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:323)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$6.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:309)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:288)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:278)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSimpleFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:269)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:263)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:246)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:238)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:188)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:98)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:67)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'eurekaService.FeignClientSpecification' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'eurekaService.FeignClientSpecification': There is already [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerClientConfiguration(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: please post the full stack trace of the thrown exception if it's possible

Comment: I posted as requested.

Comment: Similar issue discussed where the issue leads towards we can't really use multiple feign clients in spring boot using the @FeignClient annotation, because let's say as soon one client is using some authorization flow (basic, oauth2), this is applied to all other clients. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1184, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1211

Comment: In `@FeignClient`, configuration does not work when you have 2 or more `@FeignClient` with the same name but different configuration
The workaround is to use name with name="aa" it on FeignClient and and name="aaa" in the other when you have only 2.

Comment: Thanks for responses. We cannot change a name, therefore we will stay with our current solution and have a one, big feign interface.